# Properties of colon ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_6]$ be a polynomial ring and $I=(x_1x_5-x_2x_4,x_2x_6-x_3x_5)$ be an ideal.

> How to show that, $(I^2:x_1x_5-x_2x_4)=I$ ?

Comment: These are determinantal ideals. Any generalization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put $P=x_1x_5-x_2x_4$,  $Q=x_2x_6-x_3x_5$. Assume a polynomial $A$ satisfies $AP\in I^2$. Then we have a relation $$(*)\quad AP=UP^2+VQ^2+WPQ.$$ In particular, $P$ divides $VQ^2$. Since $P$ is prime and does not divide $Q$, it must divide $V$. Simplifying $(*)$ by $P$ gives the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using a computer, this can be computed in [Macaulay2](http://www.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/). Below is the computation.

> i1 : R = QQ[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6]
>
> o1 = R
>
> o1 : PolynomialRing
>
> i2 : I = ideal(x1*x5 - x2*x4, x2*x6 - x3*x5)
>
> o2 = ideal (- x2*x4 + x1*x5, - x3*x5 + x2*x6)
>
> o2 : Ideal of R
>
> i3 : I == I^2 : ideal(x1*x5 - x2*x4)
>
> o3 = true

Comment: Thanks. Can you show without M2 ?

Comment: Thinking more about it. I believe $r$ is in the colon ideal iff $r(x_1 x_5 - x_2 x_4)$ is in $I^2$ iff $r$ is in $I$.

Comment: The first iff is the definition of colon ideal, the second iff takes a quick argument now in another answer.